# Large file upload error

Tags: file-uploads

I've a site running EE 2.8.1 and the allowed filesize on the server is 512M however, if I try to upload a large PDF I receive the following error: "This form has expired. Please refresh and try again."

This error does not appear on my local, development version of the site, however I have no idea what I'd need to configure or set on the server to get this working for production.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things to think about.

Apache: Keep-Alive Timeout should be more than 5 (2GB files is around 100)

PHP: upload_max_filesize, memory_limit, max_input_time, post_max_size

Server: your /tmp partition needs to be more more than the to uploading file. Most /tmp partitions are 512M if your file is larger it won't work. (unless you use a mac at work, mac it's /tmp is not a separate partition that's why it works)

I guess that your problem lies -> /tmp

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, I can't remember how I solved it in the end, but your answer contains some solid advice.

Comment: thanks. Just started a project that contains large files...